# How to retrieve the list of updated database objects/tables ordering by recent time?

Tags: sql-server, database

I am working with a database named "MM" which has several tables.From frontend I saved some data and it successful, now I want to check the table modified/altered behind the scene as I am unaware of the RDBMS, what will be the query to check the last updated/altered table?

N.B: This is SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 1):

Try with this query it should help you:

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) AS TableName,
 last_user_update,*
FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
WHERE database_id = DB_ID( 'MM')
```